# Scroll bar changes size of second column in a two column html layout

Tags: html, css, dom

I have very basic two column layout. The left column contains menu, the right column has content. I want to position content in the middle. For menu I use absolute positioning, content has certain margin that overlaps menu, and to make content appear in the middle I added margin. However when content height is to big, the scroll bar appears and makes content shrink. And that back and force shrinking is inappropriate.

To prevent this I set max width to content element that exactly matches content width with scroll bar. I don't think that it's such a great solution, because on small screens I would still have the problem. What would you recommend in this case?

https://jsfiddle.net/vntkja1b/4/

```js
var state = true;
$('#toggle').click(function (){
 if (state){
    for(var i = 0; i< 100; i++){
       $('.some-lines').append($('<div> hello</div>'));
      }
  } else {
   $('.some-lines').empty();
  }
  state = !state;
});
```

```css
body{ margin: 0}

.container__left-col{
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
}
.container__right-col{
  margin: 0 0 0 300px;
  height:100%;
}

.content__wrapper{
  background-color: white;
  height:100%;
}

.content{
  margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
  background-color: red;
  height:100%;
  /* max-width:300px; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__left-col">
  kappa
  </div>
  <div class="container__right-col">
    <div class="content__wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="some-controll">
          <input id="toggle" type="button" value="Toggle"/>
        </div>
        <div class="some-lines">
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think width is the same, it's not shrinking your right div, but the overflow scroll bar appears that's why your full screen size is reduced to display the scroll bar.

Comment: no it shrinks, uncomment  /* max-width:300px; */ and you would instantly see the difference (or you can just track sizes in elements console). In real case I have a control in the right upper corner, when you press it, it adds some data and jumps left due to the issue. It seems it is impossible to fix current situation, I'm thinking of using @media queries and fix content width for each screen size, which is really sad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, but it works only for chrome. I noticed that gmail had kind of strange scroll bar.

So they made custom style for scrollbar and it constantly visible

```
.scrollbar {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And then they customized track so it's similar to background and hid upper/bottom arrows. So only the thumb is visible.

```
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: white;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```